# Calling method of subclass from superclass

Tags: java

I have a class "Tool" and various subclasses like "Axe" oder "Hammer". Each kind of Tool(Axe, Hammer) has at least one method which is defined in the subclass. And there is a "Worker" class with a slot for one tool at the time that can be every tool.

Tool class:

```
public abstract class Tool {

    private double durability;

    public double getDurability() {
        return durability;
    }

    public void setDurability(double durability) {
        this.durability = durability;
    }
}
```

Axe class:

```
public class Axe extends Tool {

    public void chop() {
        //chop some wood
    }
}
```

Now to set one tool for the worker:

```
Tool tool = new Axe();
```

The problem is that when i call "axe." i get getDurability() and setDurability() but not chop().

Comment: There is no `axe` variable in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call after casting to Axe

```
((Axe)tool).chop();
```

But you have to check it before casting to avoid any Exception

```
if (tool instanceof Axe) { 
    ((Axe)tool).chop(); 
}
```

Comment: That works and makes great sense because i have to check for the right tool anyway. So win win, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

```
abstract class Tool {

    private double durability;

    public double getDurability() {
        return durability;
    }

    public void setDurability(double durability) {
        this.durability = durability;
    }

    public void work(){

    }
}




class Axe extends Tool {

        @Override
        public void work() {
            this.chop();
        }

        public void chop() {
            //chop some wood
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1. But maybe make `chop` private here. And make `work` abstract in `Tool`.

Comment: @Thilo - yes that would be correct depending upon what exactly is intended from a `Tool` on its `work()` ( there could be some default behaviour ). `chop()` can be private depending upon if there are specialized `Axe` subclasses or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call `chop`, you need to know that you have an `Axe` (not just any old `Tool`).
Then you can typecast:

```
Axe axe = (Axe) tool;
axe.chop();
```

If you are not sure if this is really an `Axe`, you can check first (but this is a bit of a design smell):

```
if (tool instanceof Axe){
  Axe axe = (Axe) tool;
  axe.chop();
}
```